# How to add an SSH Key to CircleCI

Tags: ssh, circleci

I'm trying to add an ssh key(private key) to CircleCI, but I have a question.

Which private key do I have to add, private key **generated on local PC** or **generated on server what I want to access with ssh**?

[Document](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/) says that *In a terminal, generate the key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`.*

Comment: This command will not generate a key, it will generate a key *pair*. It does not matter where you run in, it only matters that you store the right key (*private/public*) at the right place. From your link, there are 2 usages of keys in CircleCI (*checkout code* and *grant service access*). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to deploy my service to VPS using CircleCI and Github. Then, I have to add private SSH key  to CircleCI.

Comment: Yes, and the public key in VPS so it can authenticate the private key holder [as explained here](https://zerowp.com/deploy-from-bitbucket-to-digitalocean-or-any-other-vps-using-circleci/)